# Reference twins and how to identify them

Tags: bibtex

I need to cite the two papers at the bottom. The other have the same family name but different surnamnes. I would like to ensure that they are distinctly  relatable.
How do I mark them in the bibliography and in text with an "a" respectively a "b" next to the year they were published?

I use `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`.

Thank you in advance

```
  @article{lee10,
      title={A hidden cost of strategic alliances under Schumpeterian dynamics},
      author={Lee, Jeho and Park, Seung Ho and Ryu, Young and Baik, Yoon-Suk},
      journal={Research Policy},
      volume={39},
      number={2},
      pages={229--238},
      year={2010},
      publisher={Elsevier}
    }

    @article{lee2010,
      title={Managing multiple facets of risk in new product alliances},
      author={Lee, Ruby P and Johnson, Jean L},
      journal={Decision Sciences},
      volume={41},
      number={2},
      pages={271--300},
      year={2010},
      publisher={Wiley Online Library}
    }
```

Comment: Which bibliography style do you employ? Incidentally, how is BibTeX supposed to "know" that Ruby P. Lee and Jeho Lee are twins? For that matter, why does it matter that they are twins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BibTex checks if all the FAMILY NAMES of the authors are the same. In your case that is not true. I did the verification using:

```
\usepackage{natbib,apalike}
```

in the preamble, and

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{yourbibfile}
```

in the document.

Comment: Thank you. I now chekced it, they are not true twins so I do not have to use a and b to relate to these papers